# column to row using "," as delimter

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of objects in column (file_column.txt) and I want to transpose this objects in row using "," as delimiter in a new file (file_row.txt).

Es.

```
file_column.txt:
Art
14f
adr
a24

file_row.txt:
Art,14f,adr,a24
```

I try to use this code:

```
paste -s -d " " tabella.txt
```

but the result it isn't right because I obtained this:

```
Art
,14f
,adr
,a24
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the right delimiter (comma) with the `-d` parameter:

```bsh
cat file
Art
14f
adr
a24
```

```bsh
paste -sd, file
Art,14f,adr,a24
```

Comment: The result is the same. The objects aren't in row but in column

Comment: You have carriage returns in the files. Run `dos2unix` on any input file. What you described is possibly the result of having `^M` or `\r`, Windows line endings, at the end of your file lines.

Comment: thank's! I've done. Now works

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

while read line
 do
  string="${string},${line}"
 done < file_column.txt

echo ${string#","} > file_row.txt
```

This works.

The `while read` construction is more portable as it uses only Bash syntax and the builtin `read`.

Comment: Paste is a POSIX tool, Bash is not, so the portability claim is not true (although that script does not contain any bashism). Also see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716).

Comment: Well, thanks for destroying me constructively. It's always nice to learn.

Comment: Hey, no intention to *destroy*, only to constructively criticize ;) And I guess we have all been there as well!